# Looking for the inverse of "frictional"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, adjectives

Does *frictional* means "that which is produced by friction"? Or is there a better word that means "that which generates friction"?

Comment: *Frictive* is the other adjectival form.

Comment: But it also appears to be a synonym, not the inverse, of frictional.

Comment: _Frictional_ need not mean "that which is produced by friction". It can refer to any kind of relation with friction or energy loss.

Comment: So then `frictional` can be used to describe `that which generates friction`?

Comment: And then I'd have the same question about `frictive`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***abrasive***
something wearing down or rubbing away by means of friction

> **[abrade](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/abrade?q=abrade)**
>   /əˈbreɪd/ *verb* [with object]
>   scrape or wear away by friction or erosion
>   late 17th century: from Latin *abradere*, from ab- 'away, from' + *radere* 'to scrape'

Answer (score 0):

***Frictive***
Of, relating to, or caused by friction. A frictive surface is one that has a high degree of friction.

***Abrasive***
 It's related but distinct: *Abrasive* is something that causes *abrasion* - that's the wearing away bit. *Frictive* is something that causes *friction*, whether or not it leads to abrasion occuring.